# move_uploaded_file / No such file or directory in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with the move_uploaded_file function this is the problem:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/imagenes/Icon.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to >open stream: No such file or directory in /home/decc98/public_html/php/insert.php on line 6
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpIBBh5U' >to '/imagenes/Icon.png' in /home/decc98/public_html/php/insert.php on line 6
>
> Insercion exitosa

Other stuff, i speak spanish so part of my code is in spanish... Anyways, my code is:

```
    <?php
    include "conexion.php";
    $ruta = "/imagenes";
    $archivo = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
    $nombreArchivo = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($archivo,$ruta."/".$nombreArchivo);
    $ruta=$ruta."/".$nombreArchivo;
    $texto = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $id = rand(1,200);
    $insertar = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablaUno VALUES('".$id."','".$ruta."','".$texto."')");
    if ($insertar) {
        echo "Inserción exitosa";
    }else{
        echo "Fallo en la inserción";
    }

    ?>
```

Please if anyone can help me I would appreciate it!

Comment: Try using a relative path `$ruta = "imagenes";` leaving out the `/` at the beginning of your folder name --- if you're using your script from the root. If not, something like `$ruta = "../imagenes";` depending on the script execution's location.

Comment: I'd check before is everything OK with $archivo variable, is file exist in temporary directory (it can be problem with access rights) and is path in $archivo variable is correct.

Comment: Also make sure that the folder is writeable. Either chmod 755 or 777. 755 is safer, and 777 is a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, i just changed $ruta = "/imagenes"; for $ruta = "../imagenes"; ^^

Comment: So that fixed it then? @user3199694 using a relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a relative path instead of an absolute path.

For example:

```
$ruta = "imagenes";
```

leaving out the `/` at the beginning of your folder name, if you're using your script from the root.

Or, something like:

```
$ruta = "../imagenes";
```

depending on the script execution's location.

Note: Using `/` is mostly used for an (server) absolute path, something to the affect of:

```
/var/user/user123/public_html/imagenes
```